# Preguntar si Maradona vino a la clase - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones, booleano, prompt

Tengo que hacer este ejercicio:

> Ingresar un listado de nombres de alumnos por pantalla. Cada vez que se ingresa un nuevo usuario, preguntar si se quiere ingresar otro utilizando la función `confirm`. En caso de que el usuario no quiera ingresar otro alumno, mostrar los siguientes resultados por consola:
>
> - Indicar la cantidad de alumnos que se ingresaron
> - Preguntar si *Maradona* vino a la clase. Hacerlo con otra función que tome un array como parámetro y retorne `true` o `false` dependiendo si lo encontró
> - Mostrar el listado de alumnos por pantalla.

Pero no sé cómo resolver la parte de si *Maradona* vino a la clase.

```js
var ingresarAlumno = confirm("Bievenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?");
var contador = 0;

if (ingresarAlumno) {
  var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumno");

  if (alumno != '') {
    contador = contador + 1;
    console.log(alumno);
  }

  while (confirm('ingresar otro?')) {
    var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumno");
    if (alumno != '') {
      contador = contador + 1;
      console.log(alumno);
    }
  }
  console.log(contador);
}
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Me parece que te falta mas código, por ejemplo: ¿dónde estás guardando a los alumnos?, te dejo una pista: investiga [arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Comment: Mariano: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado ? Más detalles sobre cómo preguntas en [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Viendo el código del compañero @fwBasic, que no lo veo mal, he conseguido una versión más compacta y sencilla de leer.

```js
// Declaramos la variable para parar el bucle
var res = true;

// Declaramos un array vacío de nombres
var arrayNombres = [];

// Declaramos un while que parará cuando el usua
while(res) {
    let nombre = prompt("Introduzca un nombre");
    // Comprobamos si el nombre está vacío
    if(nombre !== "") {
        /* Ponemos el nombre completo en minúsculas
           para un filtrado más simple
        */
        arrayNombres.push(nombre.toLowerCase());
    } else {
      alert("No se ha añadido el nombre porque está vacío");
    }

    res = confirm("¿Desea introducir otro nombre?");
}

/* Una vez terminado de ejecutar el while, 
preguntamos si Maradona vino a clase.
*/

if(arrayNombres.includes("maradona")) {
    alert("Maradona vino a clase");
} else {
    alert("Maradona no vino a clase");
}
```

Comment: Estimado si usas **`do {...} while(confirm("¿Desea introducir otro nombre?"));`** te podrías ahorrar 4 lineas de código, otra cosa, en el ejemplo del OP no esta permitido ingresar alumnos sin nombre y en tu código si lo permites ;))...

Comment: No soy muy fan de do/while, existiendo el while simple. Y ya he añadido la corrección para evitar cadenas vacías en el nombre. Gracias por el aviso @fwBasic!

Answer (score 2):

Debes de crear un `Array` como dice el enunciado y guardar los alumnos ahí.

Luego con la función recorres el `Array` buscando si está el nombre de *Maradona*.

```js
var ingresarAlumno = confirm("Bievenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?");
var contador = 0;
var alumnos = [];

if (ingresarAlumno) {
    var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumnno");

    if (alumno != '') {
        contador = contador + 1;
        console.log(alumno);
        alumnos.push(alumno);
    }

    while (confirm('ingresar otro?')) {
        var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumnno");
        if (alumno != '') { 
            contador = contador + 1;
            console.log(alumno);
            alumnos.push(alumno);
        }
    }
    
    if(VinoMaradona(alumnos))
        console.log("Vino Maradona");
    else 
        console.log("No vino Maradona");

    console.log(contador);
}

function VinoMaradona(lista)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if(lista[i] == "Maradona")
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Que respondas a este tipo de preguntas no ayuda al sitio. El OP no ha demostrado el interes, y ademas la pregunta esta incompleta.

Comment: @Srsole, no entiendo a que te refieres con que el OP no ha demostrado el interés, si hasta un ejemplo publico de lo que a hecho!... sé que hay muchos eruditos en SO pero sugiero dejar a un lado la mezquindad en favor del espíritu de SO, de ayudar al OP a resolver sus problemas e inquietudes.

Comment: Lo primero yo no me considero ningun erudito, pero yo como veo este caso es: te enseño 4 ruedas y te digo, quiero hacer un coche.... no se como se hace....; En este caso ni siquiera el OP te comenta que necesita o como ha pensado hacerlo objetos? arrays? lo almacenamos en BD? no ha dicho nada, un snippet que le pasaron en el propio ejercicio y nada mas. Eso es lo que digo.

Answer (score 1):

Estas repitiendo el código, esto lo puedes evitar usando `do {...} while(...)` en lugar de `while(...) {...} do`, también debes crear un Array u Objeto para guardar los alumnos que vas ingresando, luego usaras  este objeto para imprimir el listado de alumnos y verificar si Maradona vino a clase.

Ejemplo:

```js
var contador = 0,
 listado = {};

if (confirm("Bievenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?")){
    do {
            var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumnno");
            if (alumno != ''){  
                contador += 1;
                listado[alumno] = contador;
                console.log(alumno);
            }           
    } while(confirm('ingresar otro?'));

    console.log(contador+' registros');
    console.log('listado '+JSON.stringify(listado));
    if('Maradona' in listado)
     console.log('Maradona vino hoy puesto '+listado['Maradona'])
}
```

Para responder a @Benito-B he modificado la respuesta para mostrar como puedes recorrer un `Object` tal como lo harías con un `Arrays`, de tal forma que puedas generar un listado "útil" de la datos. ;))...

Ejemplo:

```js
var contador = 0, listado = {}, alumno;

if ( confirm( "Bievenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?" ) )
  do {
    if ( alumno = prompt( "Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumnno" ) ) {
      if ( ! ( alumno in listado ) ) {
        listado[alumno] = {};
        listado[alumno].nombre = alumno;
        listado[alumno].puesto = ++contador;
      }           
    }           
  } while( alumno && confirm( "ingresar otro?" ) );

console.log( contador +" registros" );

if ( Maradona_En( listado ) )
  console.log( "Maradona vino hoy? Si (puesto "+ listado["Maradona"].puesto +")" );
  
for ( alumno in listado ) {
  console.log( "nombre "+ listado[alumno].nombre, ", puesto "+ listado[alumno].puesto );
}
function Maradona_En( listado ) {
 return ( "Maradona" in listado );
}
```

y para quienes consideran que con un **`array`** es mejor, pues aquí se los dejo.

Ejemplo:

```js
var contador = 0, listado = [], alumno;

if ( confirm( "Bievenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?" ) )
  do {
    if ( alumno = prompt( "Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumnno" ) ) {
      if ( ! listado.includes( alumno ) ) {
        listado.push( alumno );
        contador++;
      };
    }           
  } while( alumno && confirm( "ingresar otro?" ) );

console.log( contador +" registros" );

if ( Maradona_En( listado ) )
  console.log( "Maradona vino hoy? Si (puesto "+ ( listado.indexOf("Maradona") + 1 ) +")" );
 
listado.forEach(function ( alumno ) {
  console.log( "nombre "+ alumno, ", puesto "+ ( listado.indexOf( alumno ) + 1 ) );
});

function Maradona_En( listado ) {
 return listado.includes("Maradona");
}
```

Comment: He escrito los siguientes caracteres: asd, asdf, asd y el resultado ha sido:
`listado {"asd":3,"asdf":2}`. Tal vez una lista de strings sería más apropiada que un objeto cuyos atributos tienen valores inservibles

Comment: Mismos datos: asd, asdf, asd -> 3 registros: nombre asd, puesto 3 ---- nombre asdf, puesto 2.... ahí se acaba. Donde está el puesto 1? y por qué muestra 2 registros? Sigo viendo más útil utilizar un array de strings, obtienes el mismo resultado y con menos código. Menos código = menos posibilidades de error. Hacer las cosas más complicadas de lo que necesitan ser suele causar más problemas de los que arregla

Comment: Estimado @Benito-B, gracias por intentar corregir lo incorregible, ahí esta la belleza de la programación, hay mil maneras de hacer las cosas, por otro lado, estas ingresando el alumno "asd" 2 veces, es por ello que en el listado aparece reflejado el alumno "asd" una vez, por lo que a mi concierne el reporte esta bien, te invito a que coloques una respuesta que a tu parecer consideres sea la correcta, pues es con ejemplos que ayudaras al OP a como hacer las cosas.

Comment: No pretendo corregir nada, simplemente el OP indica -> *Mostrar el listado de alumnos por pantalla.* y lo que usted muestra, caballero, no es el listado de alumnos real, pues si yo y un amigo nos llamamos igual y el profesor usa su lista, alguno de los dos se llevará una falta por no haber ido a clase. Una lista puede contener duplicados, su objeto no

Comment: Estas equivocado una lista de asistencia no puede contener duplicados.

Answer (score 1):

He intentado hacerlo lo más parecido al código que ya tenías creado para que lo puedas entender mejor.

Se crea una variable array *listado* para guardar toda la lista de alumnos, colocándolos en orden de inserción.

Ese listado será el mismo que se use en la función *hayMaradona()* la cual devuelve *true* o *false* dependiendo de si la función *listado.indexOf()* lo encuentra, devolviendo un valor distinto a *-1*.

```js
var ingresarAlumno = confirm("Bienvenido. Desea ingresar un alumno?");
var contador = 0;
var listado = [];

if (ingresarAlumno) {
  var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumno");

  if (alumno != '') {
    contador = contador + 1;
    //console.log(alumno);
    listado.push(alumno);
  }

  while (confirm('ingresar otro?')) {
    var alumno = prompt("Por favor ingrese el nombre de un alumno");
    if (alumno != '') {
      contador = contador + 1;
      //console.log(alumno);
      listado.push(alumno);
    }
  }
  
  console.log("Han ingresado "+listado.length+" alumnos")
  if(hayMaradona(listado)){
    console.log("Maradona ha venido a clase")
  }else{
    console.log("Maradona no ha venido a clase")
  }
  console.log("Listado de alumnos en la clase: "+listado);
}

function hayMaradona(listado){
    if(listado.indexOf("Maradona")!=-1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: En realidad tendría que ser... `listado.length` y no `listado.length + 1`

Comment: Correcto Eslacuare, gracias por la corrección. Ya lo he cambiado.